# Is there a way to solve a problem of biased(corrupted) dataset?

Tags: computer-vision, webcam

I`m working on the problem of russian sign language recogition and i have a some troubles with my dataset. For solving this task i decided to use classifaction network coming after segmentation network (separate hand from background and next classify it). After that i collected dataset by myself using chroma key to separate hand from backgound. It contains images collected from 20 people with help of 2 webcams. During recording i did not attach importance to the fact that the colors are distorted on one of cameras. Also i used indoorCVPR_09 as backgrounds dataset that constains indoor images.  I trained unet on this data and get 92% on training set with f1-score metric. Images for segmentaions was  loss functions was binary cross entropy. Also i calculated weight per batch becasue of class ibalance because without it network does not converge. So now i am working with this camera and have some problems during inference. I noticed reason of this problem when tried to use my network with chroma key isntead of my room wall. Webcam automaticly changed its inner settings and network started to selecting more pixels also a colors on image were shifted to the red.

I already tried some image augumentaions like adding random brightess, contrast, gamma-corection, adding random gaussian noise and and bluring.

I want some advices what try to do next. 
Is there a way to prevent changing in color perception of my webcam?
Is there a way to know what transormation was maded by my webcam(defender g lens 2577) during dataset recording to invert it?
Maybe there is some color augumenation that can help? 
How do such problems usually get solved in serious research and commercial projects?